# php DatePeriod does not return 2 days as expected

Tags: php, date, datetime

I try to get all days within a period of time. It does not matter if it is a full day or only some hours. My current code using DatePeriod does not work for me.

Example:

```
[start] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2014-01-27 22:40:40
        [timezone_type] => 1
        [timezone] => +00:00
    )

[end] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2014-01-28 17:40:40
        [timezone_type] => 1
        [timezone] => +00:00
    )

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1Day Interval
$daterange = new DatePeriod($time['start'], $interval ,$time['end']);

$return['days'] = array();

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $return['days'][] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

I would like to get

```
[0] => 2014-01-27
[1] => 2014-01-28
```

But i only get the

```
[0] => 2014-01-27
```

Is it possible to change DatePeriod parameters or something ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DatePeriod` object ignores last period. You can solve that by increasing end date by your interval:

```php
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$start->setTime(0, 0);
$end->setTime(0, 0)->add($interval);
$periods = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/94720)</kbd>

<sup>**Updated:** remove (set to 00:00:00) time parts on start and end dates, if you are only looping via days.</sup>

Comment: or you can do this without `DateInterval` and `DatePeriod` objects, like [this demo](http://3v4l.org/bKHdJ). This will even run on PHP >= 5.2.0.

Comment: very intersting solution in your comment like i wrote vor vascowhite i have to deal with splitting a timestamp

Comment: today 17 to tomorrow 17 will return 2 days, but for other cases it might return 3 instead of 2 days, ill fix it and publish it via github  project soon https://github.com/dukeatcoding/timespan-converter

Comment: @Dukeatcoding: ofc, if you have time part in end date bigger than time part in start date. If you are only looping days, then you can just "unset" time parts, like this [demo](https://eval.in/94715).

Comment: Thanks, this help me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen foul of the fact that DatePeriod ignores the last period. You can get around this by adding a DatePeriod to the end as [Glavic suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21282424/212940), or, you can construct DatePeriod using the number of intervals you want to add on, 1 in your given example:-

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // 1Day Interval
$daterange = new DatePeriod($time['start'], $interval , 1);

$return['days'] = array();

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $return['days'][] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
}
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/gdXFq).

Glavic's answer is the best option here and you should accept that, I just wanted to show you an alternative as he got in too quick with the answer as usual :)

Comment: thx for showing the alternative. i will go with glavic's answer then, i need to split a timespan timestamp to timestamp into days, weeks, month and years for a datawarehouse query do you have any further ideas ?