# Edit code to also include the last date selected

Tags: php

What changes can I apply to the code below, in order to include all the dates in the range, rather than all the dates except for the last one.  Currently if dates selected are: 01-05-2015 and 04-05-2015 ->
Result is: 
01-05-2015, 02-05-2015, 03-05-2015, whereas the desired result is: 01-05-2015, 02-05-2015, 03-05-2015, 04-05-2015.

```
    function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
  $dates = array();
  $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
  $last = new DateTime($booking_to);
  $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
  $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);

  foreach ($period as $date) {
      $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  } 

  return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282322/php-dateperiod-does-not-return-2-days-as-expected

Comment: Had already tried that one yesterday and didn't work. :) but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php#109846, add a modify on the last date.

```
function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $dates = array();
    $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
    $last = new DateTime($booking_to);
    $last = $last->modify( '+1 day' );
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
    $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);

    foreach ($period as $date) {
        $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
    }

    return $dates;
}

$dates = daterange('01-05-2015', '04-05-2015');
```